# Acumatica customer mailing settings through API

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to get Customer  Mailing Settings created through the Screen API. I am however not succeeding in getting the data saved.

Here is my code:

```
public static class CustomerManager
{
    private static Value CreateValue(
        string value,
        Command linkedCommand)
    {
        return new Value()
        {
            Value = value,
            LinkedCommand = linkedCommand
        };
    }

    private static Value CreateValueCommit(
        string value,
        Command linkedCommand)
    {
        return new Value()
        {
            Value = value,
            LinkedCommand = linkedCommand,
            Commit = true
        };
    }

    public static void ManageContact() {
        try {
            using (var context = WebServiceConnector.InitializeScreenWebService()) {
                var customerSchema = context.AR303000GetSchema();

                var commands = new List<Command>() {
                    CreateValueCommit("C00001", customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID),
                    CreateValueCommit("INVOICE", customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID),
                    CreateValue("mail@mail.com", customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccountEmailAddress),
                    CreateValueCommit("InvoiceNotification", customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.NotificationTemplate),
                    customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                    CreateValueCommit("Contact", customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactType),
                    CreateValueCommit("Doe John, Dr.", customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactID),
                    customerSchema.Actions.Save,
                    customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID,
                    customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccountEmailAddress,
                    customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactID
                };

                var customer = context.AR303000Submit(commands.ToArray());

                context.Logout();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

The only value that gets saved correctly is the Notification Template.

Upon debug, I inspected the Mailing Recipient, and the value is in my customer return object. But there is nothing on the Customer screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Mailing Settings tab is not an easy thing to automate thought Web Services because of the following reasons:

- initial mailing settings are defined on the Customer Class level. Users are allowed to either modify the initial settings or create new Branch-specific settings. Only one mailing setting can be defined for every MailingID/Branch pair
- the Recipients grid displays only recipients defined for the current mailing setting
- **DisplayMode** set to ***Text*** for the Email Account column requires to change originally generated FieldName from `EMailAccountID` to `EMailAccountID!Address`. Otherwise the API will ignore values defined for this column:

  ```
  Content customerSchema = context.GetSchema();
  customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccount.FieldName += "!Address";
  ```

  Definition of the Mailings grid in Aspx:

  ```
  <px:PXGrid ID="gridNS" runat="server" SkinID="DetailsInTab" Caption="Mailings" ... >
      ...
      <Levels>
          <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="NotificationSources" DataKeyNames="SourceID,SetupID">
              <RowTemplate>
                  ...
              </RowTemplate>
              <Columns>
                  ...
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="EMailAccountID" DisplayMode="Text" Width="200px" />
                  ...
              </Columns>
              ...
          </px:PXGridLevel>
      </Levels>
  </px:PXGrid>
  ```

Below are 3 samples showing how to work with the Mailing Settings tab though Screen-Based API:

1. To insert new recipient for the initial mailing setting defined on the Customer Class level:

   ```
   Screen context = new Screen();
   context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
   context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/AR303000.asmx";
   context.Login(username, password);

   try
   {
       Content customerSchema = context.GetSchema();
       var commands = new Command[]
       {
           new Value
           {
               Value = "ABCSTUDIOS",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
           },

           new Key
           {
               Value = "='INVOICE'",
               FieldName = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID.FieldName,
               ObjectName = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID.ObjectName
           },
           customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID,

           customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Contact",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactType,
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Harper, Travis",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactID,
               Commit = true
           },
           customerSchema.Actions.Save
       };
       context.Submit(commands);
   }
   finally
   {
       context.Logout();
   }
   ```
2. To update the initial mailing setting defined on the Customer Class level mailing setting and add new recipient for it:

   ```
   Screen context = new Screen();
   context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
   context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/AR303000.asmx";
   context.Login(username, password);

   try
   {
       Content customerSchema = context.GetSchema();
       customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccount.FieldName += "!Address";

       var commands = new Command[]
       {
           new Value
           {
               Value = "ACTIVESTAF",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
           },

           new Key
           {
               Value = "='INVOICE'",
               FieldName = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID.FieldName,
               ObjectName = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID.ObjectName
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "admin@revisiontwo.com",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccount,
               Commit = true
           },

           customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Contact",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactType,
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Dunnaville, Linda",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactID,
               Commit = true
           },
           customerSchema.Actions.Save
       };
       context.Submit(commands);
   }
   finally
   {
       context.Logout();
   }
   ```
3. To create new Branch-specific mailing setting and add new recipient for it:

   ```
   Screen context = new Screen();
   context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
   context.Url = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/Soap/AR303000.asmx";
   context.Login(username, password);

   try
   {
       Content customerSchema = context.GetSchema();

       customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccount.FieldName += "!Address";
       var commands = new Command[]
       {
           new Value
           {
               Value = "ABCVENTURE",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
           },

           customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
           new Value
           {
               Value = "INVOICE",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.MailingID,
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "HQ",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.Branch,
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "admin@revisiontwo.com",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsMailings.EmailAccount,
               Commit = true
           },

           customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Contact",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactType,
           },
           new Value
           {
               Value = "Palmer, Steve",
               LinkedCommand = customerSchema.MailingSettingsRecipients.ContactID,
               Commit = true
           },
           customerSchema.Actions.Save
       };
       context.Submit(commands);
   }
   finally
   {
       context.Logout();
   }
   ```